# Explain how these answers were computed from this graph and equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformational-geometry

this question was given on a previous exam:

**Below is a graph of a function y = f(x) with a few key points.**
[image: graph of function]

**Draw a graph of y = 3f(2x) + 4, with the corresponding points shown in the graph above.**

And the answer key is given as the points:

**(-1/2,10), (1/2, 10), (1/4), (3/2,10)**

for the new points on the new graph; but, I am confused as to how these answers were computed. It would be great if someone can explain to me how these answers were computed.

Thank you!

Comment: The graph of $y=f(2x)$ is scaling of $y=f(x)$ in $x$ directions by a factor of $1/2$; ie. it "shrinks" the graph of $y=f(x)$. So, for example the point $(-1,2)$ is mapped to $(-1/2,2)$. Then $y=3f(2x)$ is a shrinking followed by scaling in direction of $y$ axes by a factor of $3$. So $(-1/2,2)$ maps to $(-1/2,6)$. Finally, $y=3f(2x)+4$ translates this graph in positiv e $y$ direction by $4$, so $(-1/2,6)$ goes to $(-1/2,10)$. Same thing applies to other points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a function defined by some equation $y=f(x)$ as in this problem and suppose each $y$ in the equation is replaced by a linear expression $ay+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants, $a\ne0$. Suppose also that each $x$ in the equation is replaced by a linear expression $cx+d$ where $c\ne0$ and $d$ are constants.

Then one will have a new functional equation which maps each straight line connecting any two points of the original graph to a straight line connecting two points of the new, transformed graph. Such a transformation is called a **linear** transformation.

In order to use this information to graph $y=3f(2x)+4$ we must first solve for $f(2x)$ which we find is

$$\frac{1}{3}y-\frac{4}{3}=f(2x)$$

which we compare to

$$y=f(x)$$

to see that the linear transformation which is being applied to the given graph is

$$x\,\to\,2x,\qquad y\,\to\,\frac{1}{3}y-\frac{4}{3}$$

Since the graph of $y=f(x)$ consists of straight line segments and since this is a linear transformation, we just have to find out where the four endpoints of $y=f(x)$ are mapped and connect them with straight line segments.

We can do this with each of the four points as follows:

1. $2x=-1$ so $x=-\frac{1}{2}.\qquad$ $\frac{1}{3}y-\frac{4}{3}=2$ so  $y=10$. Therefore $(-1,2)\,\to\,\left(-\frac{1}{2},10\right)$
2. $2x=1$ so $x=\frac{1}{2}.\qquad$ $\frac{1}{3}y-\frac{4}{3}=2$ so  $y=10$. Therefore $(1,2)\,\to\,\left(\frac{1}{2},10\right)$
3. $2x=2$ so $x=1.\qquad$ $\frac{1}{3}y-\frac{4}{3}=0$ so  $y=4$. Therefore $(2,0)\,\to\,(1,4)$
4. $2x=3$ so $x=\frac{3}{2}.\qquad$ $\frac{1}{3}y-\frac{4}{3}=2$ so  $y=10$. Therefore $(3,2)\,\to\,\left(\frac{3}{2},10\right)$

The original graph is mapped to the new graph shown in red.

Below the graph is a second way to work the problem which requires finding the piece-wise equations for the given graph.

[image: Graph of solution]

There is a second way to work this kind of problem if you are given the equation. This particular function consists of three line segments "glued" together.

$y=\begin{cases}
2 & \text{for }-1\le x<1\\
-2x+4 & \text{for }\phantom{-}1\le x<2\\
2x-4 & \text{for }\phantom{-}2\le x\le3\\
\end{cases}$

Now apply the transformation $x\,\to\,2x,\quad y\,\to\,\frac{1}{3}y-\frac{4}{3}$

$\frac{1}{3}y-\frac{4}{3}=\begin{cases}
2 & \text{for }-1\le 2x<1\\
-4x+4 & \text{for }\phantom{-}1\le 2x<2\\
4x-4 & \text{for }\phantom{-}2\le 2x\le3\\
\end{cases}$

Remove fractions by multiplying all three equations by $3$ to obtain

$y-4=\begin{cases}
6 & \text{for }-1\le 2x<1\\
-12x+12 & \text{for }\phantom{-}1\le 2x<2\\
12x-12 & \text{for }\phantom{-}2\le 2x\le3\\
\end{cases}$

Then add four to each side of the three equations.

$y=\begin{cases}
10      & \text{for }-1\le 2x<1\\
-12x+16 & \text{for }\phantom{-}1\le 2x<2\\
 12x-12 & \text{for }\phantom{-}2\le 2x\le3\\
\end{cases}$

Finally, solve the three inequalities for $x$ to express the domain correctly.

$y=\begin{cases}
10      & \text{for }-\frac{1}{2}\le x<\frac{1}{2}\\
-12x+16 & \text{for }\phantom{-}\frac{1}{2}\le x<1\\
12x-12 & \text{for }\phantom{-}1\le x\le\frac{3}{2}\\
\end{cases}$

This gives the piece-wise equations for the transformed graph.

Note that the actual reason for learning this is so that you can do the process **in reverse**. That is when the translating, reflecting and scale changes comes into play.

For example, an equation such as

\begin{equation}
y=3+\sqrt{x+1}
\end{equation}

can be re-written as

\begin{equation}
y-3=\sqrt{x+1}
\end{equation}

so that we recognize it as the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ transformed by $x\,\to\,x+1,\quad y\,\to\,y-3$ which translates the graph graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ by $-1$ units horizontally and $+3$ units vertically.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was explained mathematically great. I was also wondering, do you think this new graph can be generated from using just transformations (e.g. translations, reflection, magnifications)?

Comment: Yes it can be done in terms of translations, scale changes (magnification & shrinking) but that approach is easier when you have the equation of the function.  I will add that to my answer so you will see how to do it when you have the equation of the graph. In this case it will be a piece-wise defined function so first I will re-write it in that form. Give me a few minutes to write that up.